# Что означают значения атрибута os.name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос, кроссплатформенность

Разбираюсь с модулем os. В атрибуте os.name лежит одно из значений: posix, nt, os2, ce, java, riscos.

Posix, nt, os2, rscos - это понятно. Что значат остальные, java и ce?

В доках не нашел объяснение

Comment: Вроде бы Jython и Windows CE

Answer (score 3):

Существует [много различных реализаций Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations). Главной из которых является [`CPython`](https://github.com/python/cpython). С ней также совместимы: [IronPython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IronPython), [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Jython) и [PyPy](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPy).

- в [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L46-L86)  в качестве значения атрибута `os.name` поддерживаются:

  - posix
  - nt
- [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Src/StdLib/Lib/os.py#L48-L106):

  - posix
  - nt
  - ce - Windows CE
- [Jython](https://github.com/jythontools/jython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L42-L134):

  - posix
  - nt
  - os2
  - ce - Windows CE
  - riscos - RISC OS
  - ibmi - IBM
  - java - Jython
- [PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/5605eba9586b64408247d451dce2670ad7c65c08/lib-python/2.7/os.py#lines-41:117):

  - posix
  - nt
  - os2
  - ce - Windows CE
  - riscos - RISC OS